# In this code, within the admin subclass, how does the def show_privileges function work exactly? Why does the function call on itself?

Tags: python, inheritance, subclass

```
class User:

    """Simulating user profiles and their use."""
    
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
        """Initialise user attributes."""
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.login_attempts = 0
        
    def describe_user(self):
        """Print names of user."""
        print(f"First name: {self.first_name}")
        print(f"Last name: {self.last_name}")
        
    def greet_user(self):
        """Display greeting to user along with name of user."""
        print(f"Welcome, {self.first_name} {self.last_name}!")
    
    def increment_login_attempts(self):
        """Register the number of login attempts made."""
        self.login_attempts += 1
    
    def reset_login_attempts(self):
        """Resets login attempts to 0."""
        self.login_attempts = 0
    

class Privileges():

    """Outlines and simulates usage of administrator privileges."""

    def __init__(self, privileges):
        """Initialise attributes for privileges class."""
        self.privileges = privileges
        
    def show_privileges(self):
        for privilege in self.privileges:
            print(f"\t{privilege}")


class Admin(User):

    """Defining an administrator and relevant privileges/data."""
    
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, privileges):
        """Initialise attributes as in parent user class."""
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name)
        self.privileges = Privileges(privileges)
        
    def show_privileges(self):
        """Displays privileges that the administrator has."""
        self.privileges.show_privileges()


privileges_list = ['Can delete posts', 'Can ban users']

admin_1 = Admin('Alfred', 'Obadiah', privileges_list)

admin_1.describe_user()

admin_1.greet_user()

admin_1.show_privileges()
```

Comment: It _doesn't_ call itself.

Comment: What do you mean ? `Admin.show_privileges` calls `Privileges.show_privileges` that just it

Comment: ``Admin.show_privileges` calls `Privileges.show_privileges`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: okay I think I know where my misunderstanding came from. The show_privileges method in admin subclass is worded the same as the show_privileges method in the privileges class

Comment: got caught up in trying to figure out the syntax of a function calling on itself